# Call shell script from python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

Attempting to call a shell script with options from a python script.
The line **./dropbox_uploader.sh -s download /test/pictures pictures/** runs fine via SSH but errors when called from a python script:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./dropbox_uploader.sh -s download /test/pictures pictures/'])
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sync.py", line 2, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['./dropbox_uploader.sh -s download /test/pictures pictures/'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you post the errors?

Comment: Is your working directory the one containing the dropbox_uploader.sh script?

Comment: Due to the way you've called it, `subprocess.call()` is looking for a file named "./dropbox_uploader.sh -s download /test/pictures pictures/". Which obviously doesn't exist. See bereal's on how to call it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if the first argument of `subprocess.call` is a list, it must contain the executable and arguments as separate items:

```
subprocess.call(['./dropbox_uploader.sh', '-s', 
                 'download', '/test/pictures', 'pictures/'])
```

or, maybe, more convenient:

```
import shlex
cmd = './dropbox_uploader.sh -s download /test/pictures pictures/'
subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```

There is also an option to delegate parsing and execution to the shell:

```
cmd = './dropbox_uploader.sh -s download /test/pictures pictures/'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

(But please note the [security warning](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments))

Comment: the first argument may be a string but it is interpreted differently from a list. OPs issue is that `Popen` interprets a single item list argument as the path to the program therefore passing the whole command line leads to `No such file or directory` error (there is no program named like `program arg1 arg2 etc`)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks, I definitely was not clear enough. Hope, now it's better.

Comment: not quite. A *string* argument where the value is the whole command line may succeed on Windows but a list argument with a single item (as in OPs case) where the value is the whole command line will fail everywhere.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian didn't know about Windows. Thanks, fixed.